# standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory - docker problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have a problem with the docker, when running the command `docker-compose up -d --build` 3 containers `app, database, api` are created within the application `innovation`, however when accessing the docker terminal in the api container I get this error`` this is my docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    entrypoint: ./.docker/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: quimiweb-innovation-api
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      FRONTEND_URL: ${FRONTEND_URL}
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./api/:/home/node/api
    networks:
      - app-network

  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: quimiweb-innovation-database
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      - app-network
    volumes:
      - .database/:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  app:
    build: ./app/
    entrypoint: ./.docker/entrypoint.sh
    container_name: quimiweb-innovation-app
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK: ${SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK}
    ports: 
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/home/node/app       

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  app-volume:
```

My entrypoint.sh from api:

```
#!/bin/bash

yarn
yarn develop
```

Comment: Please share your `entrypoint.sh`

Comment: #!/bin/bash

yarn
yarn develop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my case, I resolved it by changing the line endings from `CRLF` to `LF` for the `entrypoint.sh` file

**Edit**

In Notepad++ on the bottom panel on to the Right, right-click on the area `Windows (CR LF)` and select `UNIX (LF)` this should replace all `CRLFs` with `LFs`.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: In Notepad++ on the bottom panel on to the Right, right click on the area Windows (CR LF) and select UNIX (LF) this should replace all CRLFs with LFs, thank you

Answer (score 10):

This error may also occur when starting an image built on a `64-bit x86` agent but running on a `64-bit Arm` container host.

Answer (score 3):

For me the line endings were already LF, I had removed all the images and rebuilt them but before building, I found I was missing the shebang -

> #!/bin/bash

I just added that and rebuilt the container and found it working.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, resolved it as Thyi by changing the line endings. Also had to rebuild the image before the change took effect.